# Centos 7 - I can't fix the datetime

Tags: linux, centos, date

It's NOT a VM. Physical server. Centos 7

I have tried to fix the time with:

```
date -s "04/03/2022 01:06:31"
```

or

```
timedatectl set-time 01:06:31
```

But it is impossible, it shows always 8 hours more as local time:

```
[root@localhost ~]# timedatectl status
      Local time: Sun 2022-04-03 09:06:31 CEST
  Universal time: Sun 2022-04-03 07:06:31 UTC
        RTC time: Sun 2022-04-03 07:06:31
       Time zone: Europe/Madrid (CEST, +0200)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
                  Sun 2022-03-27 01:59:59 CET
                  Sun 2022-03-27 03:00:00 CEST
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
                  Sun 2022-10-30 02:59:59 CEST
                  Sun 2022-10-30 02:00:00 CET

[root@localhost ~]# date
date
Sun Apr  3 09:06:32 CEST 2022
```

The timezone `Europe/Madrid` is OK

Any idea to fix it?

---

New tests:

```
[root@localhost ~]# hwclock
Mon 04 Apr 2022 01:31:35 PM CEST  -0.250859 seconds
[root@localhost ~]# date
Mon Apr  4 20:31:30 CEST 2022
[root@localhost ~]# timedatectl
      Local time: Mon 2022-04-04 20:31:34 CEST
  Universal time: Mon 2022-04-04 18:31:34 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2022-04-04 11:31:43
       Time zone: Europe/Madrid (CEST, +0200)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
                  Sun 2022-03-27 01:59:59 CET
                  Sun 2022-03-27 03:00:00 CEST
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
                  Sun 2022-10-30 02:59:59 CEST
                  Sun 2022-10-30 02:00:00 CET
[root@localhost ~]#
```

The time is OK on hwclock but it's wrong on timedatectl and date :(

The timezone is OK

Any idea?

Comment: Is this a VM? If yes, what's the time and timezone configuration of the host?

Comment: i agree with gerald, mostly like is the host the issue specifically if its a Linux box

Comment: It's not a VM, it is a server, that machine: https://www.pciex.net/products/tbs-moi-pro-amd-iptv-streaming-server?lang=es&variant=6122883317792

Comment: I have changed the time on the BIOS. The time had 6 hours more... i set the Spanish time, but now in centos has 2 hours more, 15:20 instead of 13:20 :( The timezona is OK in timedatectl but the local time is wrong and the date command also has a wrong date